# How to force Chrome to automatically remove <b> tags from HTML

Tags: html

Google results bold (using `<b>` tags) any words in the URL and description of the search results. I'm looking to automatically remove the `<b>` tags throughout the results.

Anyone know a quick and dirty way to do this live inside the search results without having to manually modify the html?

[image: Image of <b> tags in Google Result]

Comment: Well, obviously you can write a simple javascript routine iterating through the DOM, easiest as a Greasemonkey script, or you add a css rule that overwrites the font settings of the tag.

Comment: You can install the "stylish" extension and set the font weight of the `b` tags to `normal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oh1df3bk/1/

Instead of removing them just make the css match the normal font weight.

just add this to your CSS:

`b{font-weight: normal;}`

Comment: This definitely removed the style, but unfortunately, the <b> tags are preventing another extension from working. I should have included details about this, but thought that changing the style might do the trick.

Chrome extension "Multi-highlight" to show websites already on a list of existing clients. As I'm going through search results, I want to make sure URLs on my existing list are highlighted, so I go through website that's already on my list. 

Somehow, this plugin won't highlight URLs that have partial <b> tags in them, even after removing the style using the suggested CSS override.

Comment: The more I look at it, the more it seems that Multi-highlight somehow ignores anything that's separated. It'll find it if "nydivorcefirm.com" is on the list and in the code, but Google breaks up results so they're on their own lines. nyccriminallawyer.com becomes "nyc" "criminal" "lawyer" ".com/" and Multi-highlight doesn't even see it. Not sure if it's even possible to merge these elements together. A manual page search in Chrome, of course, finds it right away. Sorry for the confusion, this is just frustrating.

Comment: Would this solution work for you then? using javascript http://jsfiddle.net/DGTh5/

Comment: Thank you for the response! It does remove the <b> tags, but it leaves the URL sliced up when I look a bit closer. http://imgur.com/6JbbcSy Multi-highlight still won't highlight when it's like this.

Comment: Adam Buchanan Smith's comment directly above does indeed remove the <b> tags!

Answer (score 0):

Like Adam said, you can just put the following CSS:

```
b {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Personally, I recommend also adding the `color` you want it to be. You see, every browser has a different interpretation of HTML. So browser A can say: `<b>` tags will be bold . However, browser B can say: `<b>` tags won't be bold but will be red.

Browsers can just change the rules like that so I recommend using:

```
b {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: the color you want;
}
```